# Sub Main Not Found when using CompileAssemblyFromSource

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, exe

Im trying to create a code editor. But the compiler is not working properly.
When i try to compile, it says: Sub Main was not found in Module1
**Here is my current code:**

```
 Public Sub generateFile()
    If ExeGen.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        VBSourceCodee = "Imports System" & vbNewLine & "Module Module1" & vbNewLine & "Sub Main()" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & VBSourceCodee & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "End Sub" & vbNewLine & "End Module"
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(VBSourceCodee)
        MsgBox(VBSourceCodee)
        Dim Provider As CodeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic")
        Dim cp As CompilerParameters = New CompilerParameters()
        cp.GenerateExecutable = True
        cp.GenerateInMemory = False
        cp.CompilerOptions = " /target:winexe /m:Module1"
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange({"System.dll"}.ToArray)
        cp.OutputAssembly = ExeGen.FileName
        cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
        Dim Result As CompilerResults = Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, VBSourceCodee)
        If Result.Errors.HasErrors Then
            Dim ErrorString As String = "Compiler error:"
            For Each Err As CompilerError In Result.Errors
                ErrorString &= Err.ToString & vbCrLf
            Next
            MsgBox(ErrorString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error while compiling")
        Else
            Process.Start(ExeGen.FileName)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Added: `cp.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange({"System.dll", "Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll"})` and `Dim VBSourceCodee As String = "Dim f1 As New System.Windows.Forms.Form()" & vbCrLf & "f1.Text = ""New Form""" & vbCrLf & "f1.ShowDialog()"` (which is then added to the string you already have) and the Form with title `New Form` pops up.